# WDIO Javascript Mocha/Chai crashes NPM when expect fails

Tags: webdriver-io

When running a test, the it blocks are being executed and I'm getting this output.

What I am unable to understand is why the npm command is exiting with an error?

```
3) GAMETRIBE CELL C WAP DOI - SUCCESS FLOW Webdriver should target and click the subscription CTA:
An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("[class='button']").
running phantomjs
Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("[class='button']").
    at getText() - index.js:312:3


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriver_typescript@1.0.0 test-cellc: `node ./node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js && node ./node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio ./dist/wdio.conf.mcm.js --suite cellcWapDoi`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriver_typescript@1.0.0 test-cellc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/davidabes/.npm/_logs/2017-12-14T06_44_07_155Z-debug.log
```

My test cases look like this:

```
export default function() {
it('Webdriver should target and click the subscription CTA', function() {
    const yesLink = browser.element("[class='button']");
    console.log(yesLink.getText());
    console.log(yesLink.getTagName());
    yesLink.click();
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why aren't you using `browser.element('.button')` instead of `[class="button"]`?

Comment: Because it havent found the required element ([class='button']). This is expected behaviour though. You should add browser.waitForVisible() command before doing any action with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if any of the tests fail, then it seems mocha exits with an error code of 1 ... I just can't remember where in the docs I read this.